# Why is iPhone adding a '1' to my phone numbers when sending a text?

Tags: iphone, text

I sent a text message to (123) 456-7890 and an error message immediately appeared to "use a valid 10-digit phone number" and showed the number I used with a 1 before the area code. I tried deleting the contact's number and re-entering it, but the same thing happened. Why is the phone adding a 1? I've searched through settings (and I did turn off international dialing help to no avail). Is this a setting issue or...?

Comment: It sounds like the number you supplied can't receive texts but the error message is wrong or at least misleading.  iPhones tend to add +1 to a number stored from an incoming call or text.

Answer (score 3):

The US telephone system use a #1 in front of USA area codes.

If you with in the same area then you do not need to dial it.

Even if you dial '1 in local calls it will be just ignored.

You phone automatically adds a #1 anyway so you do not forget it.

However if you are outside the area then #1 is needed in front of the number.

In modern days devices the #1 is hidden but it is dialed automatically.

Comment: "If you with in the same area then you do not need to dial it."  Except if you live in an area code with 10-digit mandatory dialing, such as [these](http://www.nanpa.com/enas/npasRequiring10DigitReport.do)

Answer (score 2):

I was just able to duplicate this behavior sending a text to a number not in service.

The exact error message arrives as a text message from a network number and reads "1XXXYYYZZZZ Error Invalid Number. Please Re-send using a valid 10 digit mobile number or short code." (where XXXYYYZZZZ is the bad phone number).

It means either you are texting a number that is not a mobile, or "I'm sorry the number you have texted is not in service"

Answer (score 0):

Texting with the international service if you bring an Iphone from the US you have to add #1 in front of the local 8 digit number. You can make a voice call by simply dialing the 8 digit number. I would suggest when placing new contacts in your phone to add a separate contact for voice and one for text.
Scott S.